# I am having problems port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I have looked at guides and solutions online but it seems to not be exactly the same as my problem.
I think I have successfully port forwarded but I can't access it from External IP. I can access my web server through localhost and local IP from another device without any problems but when I try to access it from another Wi-Fi, it says "Connection timed out". To clarify things further, I have also configured my firewall not to block the port

[This is the user interface for port forwarding on my router which I have put my local IP in A and external IP in B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNJkl.png)

I have asked similar questions on StackOverflow, Webmasters, and ServerFault but it is off-topic on all of them. I hope it is relevant here.

Comment: Guess: Your ISP uses [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), which ISPs increasingly do, and therefore you cannot port forward from your external IP. If that is the case, you need to pay someone to give you an external IP address for that; either your ISP through a business contract, or some cloud provider.

Comment: Is there a way to check if my ISP uses Carrier Grade NAT or not?

Comment: If your router cannot port forward from the external IP, that's a strong indication... otherwise you can ask your ISP.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Pretty sure that is what's happening. Thank you for your help, dirkt.